# paintComponent() method not drawing to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

The JFrame and JPanel show up, but the paintComponent method isn't drawing on the JPanel. I only see the JLabel, JTextField and JButton that I added but not what should be drawn on the JPanel.

**update; question has been answered:** The circles actually were being drawn to the JPanel but I got the coordinates wrong so they were being drawn outside of the frame.

**JFrame class:**

```
package h02;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Circles extends JFrame {

    public Circles() {

    // JFrame and its properties

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocation(100, 100);
    frame.setTitle("Circles");
    frame.add(new CirclesPanel());
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Circles();
    }

}
```

**JPanel class:**

```
    package h02;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class CirclesPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        // Fields

    private JTextField enterDiameter;
    private JButton drawButton;
    private int diameter;
    private final int Y = 470;

    // making the panel

    public CirclesPanel() {

        enterDiameter = new JTextField("100", 5);
        enterDiameter.addActionListener(this);
        drawButton = new JButton("Teken");
        drawButton.addActionListener(this);
        add(new JLabel("Diameter"));
        add(enterDiameter);
        add(drawButton);

    }

    // find the diameter

    public void findDiameter() {

        int diameterString = Integer.parseInt(enterDiameter.getText());
        diameter = diameterString;
    }

    // draw circles


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int centre = getWidth() / 2;
        g.drawLine(30, Y, Y , Y);
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillOval(centre, Y, diameter, diameter);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(centre, Y, diameter, diameter);
        g.drawOval(centre, Y, diameter / 2, diameter);
    }

    // on action performed...

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        findDiameter();
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: If this were my code/problem, I'd try to debug, either by using a debugger or by putting println statements in your paintComponent method to see what Y (although this should be constant), centre, and diameter are when the method is called.

Comment: How come you refer to `EnterDiameter` one moment, then `enterDiameter` the next? (Note the uppercase and lowercase 'e'.)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Y = 470, centre = 249, diameter = 0. I'm not sure why it's not finding the diameter.

Comment: Kirstoffer, it could be the spelling/capitalization problem alluded to by @Arkanon. Also, you're drawing down below the GUI.

Comment: @Arkanon I'll edit that, I changed all the variables, methods etc. from Dutch to English to make it easier for people to help me here. The code is working except for the fact that my circles aren't being drawn.

Comment: Try resizing the frame and the circle should appear

Comment: Edit: actually, I see the circles being drawn now, I just messed up the coordinates. Thanks everyone.

Comment: well did you click the button?

Comment: @Reimeus I had to do that, yes, I assumed the circles would be drawn right away since I set a default value in the enterDiameter JTextField.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your "Y" in CirclesPanel. Elements are drawn but outside the frame, try reducing Y, than surely you'll see your elements.

Alternatively increase the frame size.